# Gatling adding pause when using throttling in simulation

Tags: load-testing, gatling, throttling, pause

for API performance testing using Gatling, whenever I setup a user or QPS, I use below configuration to manage my max QPS and to have consistent QPS throughout test duration.

setUp(
scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(2) during (UserRampup seconds))
)
.throttle(
reachRps(TotalQPS) in (QPSRampup seconds),
holdFor(60 minutes)
)
.protocols(httpProtocol)
.maxDuration(Duration minutes)

Now this is working fine, but in one of the scenario, I need to add pause between 2 requests. What I observed is, that when I use "throttle", it does not take any pause or sleep or pace in consideration. Is there any way in which I can use pause while having "throttle" in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. `throttle` disables `pause`s so it can take over throughput generation.

Comment: Hi Stephane
Thank you for the help and the update

I have one doubt regarding gatling open and close model testing

Now as per docs, I am using this "constantUsersPerSec(2)" which is part of open model testing, where it will not wait for response and send another request irrespective of received response. If I use throttling with this, does it converts to close model ? As I have seen Request QPS drops with high response time with throttling

Comment: constantUsersPerSec starts new users irrespective of concurrent users. It's not related to requests unless your users only perform one single request.